# Datatable clumping all user information in 2 tables

Tags: visualforce, html, datatable, table

I'm iterating over a list of objects in my visual force page. The goal of the iteration is to create 2 different tables

```
Name | Stage | Recommendation
Bob. | 1st.  | Pass

Questions | Answer | Comments
What is color of sky | Blue | N/A
```

What is happening right now is that there are 2 tables but with all the information of the objects. Is it possible to have it so when I'm on `Bob` then I can have 2 tables and then when I'm on `Nancy` it's another 2 different tables rather than clumping all the information together? Would be easy to read when I'm looking at each `User` rather than all.

Here is my VF page code :

```
<apex:datatable width="100%" value="{!candidates}" var="candidate" border="2">

    <apex:facet name="header">
        <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Name</th>
                <th width="25%">Stage</th>
                <th width="25%">Recommendation</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:facet>

    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Name}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Stage}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Recommendation}"/>
</apex:datatable>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 2 apex:datatable in your markup to display two tables with separate columns

```
<apex:datatable width="100%" value="{!candidates}" var="candidate" border="2">

    <apex:facet name="header">
        <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Name</th>
                <th width="25%">Stage</th>
                <th width="25%">Recommendation</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:facet>

    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Name}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Stage}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Recommendation}"/>
</apex:datatable>

<apex:datatable width="100%" value="{!candidates}" var="candidate" border="2">

    <apex:facet name="header">
        <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Questions</th>
                <th width="25%">Answer</th>
                <th width="25%">Comments</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:facet>

    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Questions}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Answer}"/>
    <apex:column width="25%" value="{!candidate.Comments}"/>
</apex:datatable>
```